# Adding PHP to Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache

Where I work, we use ancient technology that belongs in a museum. Further I have to get everything done through system admins.

They are telling me in order to get PHP, they will need to upgrade the operating system as well as the Apache version.

```
lcas100[67]% uname -a
Linux lcas100 2.6.9-11.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri May 20 18:26:27 EDT 2005 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
lcas100[68]% cat /etc/*-release
LSB_VERSION="1.3"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant)
lcas100[75]% /ots/apache/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/1.3.31 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov  3 2004 18:47:31
```

This doesn't make sense to me because apparently Apache 1.3.x supports PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache.php

Furthermore, we have another machine that runs PHP and is running the exact same OS and OS version. The reason I want it on the former machine is because it is mounted on a different file system.

Lastly they tell me that all software the Apache webserver runs will need to be reinstalled/recompiled (assuming an Apache upgrade WAS needed). I am not even sure about this.

Are they full of it? Thanks

Comment: why dont you just install it and show them?

Comment: While it should run on Apache 1.3.x without recompiling Apache (unless you've got an odd custom build), you should consider if you want to use such old versions of PHP/Apache for new code...

Comment: If it came to it, you could run PHP via CGI.  Requires little to no change to Apache (basically, config changes), and PHP just needs compiling and setting up.  (I wouldn't trust the version available via package manager from a system that old.)  This seems more a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) than here, though.

Comment: @Iain: I'm pretty sure any rules about spamming apply across all of SE.  :)

Comment: @cHao It's the only way to make sure that each person responsible for the bad migration gets a notification letting them know that their migration is bad and to be more thoughtful in the future.

Comment: @cHao Well stated. Completely irrelevant in this comment thread, but well stated nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using mod_php with apache. Apache shouldn't need recompiling, although it could be compiled with some options which make it incompatible with the mod_php module I guess.

The alternative if they refuse to is to use something like PHP-FPM. This would basically exact as an external service which apache can route PHP requests and return the response. More information available at http://blog.nexcess.net/2012/03/16/using-php-fpm-with-apache-2-2/ (similar to 1.3 instructions)